# Paste a copied cell into a filtered section of a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I get as far as the paste and it breaks

Not sure how to paste the value from Sheet1 cell B3

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pv As PivotItem
Dim copiedValue As Variant

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
     ' Get the copied value from the clipboard
    copiedValue = Application.ClipboardFormats(1)
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
     Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTest")
     Set pf = pt.PivotFields("xxxx")
         
     pf.ClearAllFilters
     
    'With ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet2").pf("xxxx")
     For Each pv In pf.PivotItems
           pv.Visible = True
           Next pv
    
    Have tried a loop 
    
    For Each pv In pf.PivotItems
       If pv.Value = copiedValue Then
        pv(pv.Value).Visible = True
       Else
        pv(pv.Value).Visible = False
         End If
    Next pv
```

also tried to paste values
both fail at the point of paste

Comment: Maybe try like this... if your pf is in Report Filter : `pf.ClearAllFilters:pf.currentpage= sheets("Sheet1").range("B3").value`. If the pf is in Row Labels : `pf.ClearAllFilters:pf.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=sheets("Sheet1").range("B3").value`